# Does basic_ostream<>::flush() actually flush at the kernel-level

Tags: c++

Does `basic_ostream<>::flush()` just issue the buffer to the kernel or does the standard also mandate a kernel-level flush afterwards ?

I continously wrote some C-strings to a std::string and wrote this string to a non-binary ofstream when it became >= 64kB in size. Issuing a flush after each buffered string made only a small difference even when writing half a gigabyte of buffers. Maybe it's just the kernel-flush that's that fast with my PCIe 4.0 SSD.

Comment: Strictly neither, although the former is closer to the truth. C++ standard has nothing to say about kernels. The answer to the question in the title is probably no. Although you never know how a particular implementation will work, there is no requirement for a kernel level flush.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about kernels, but maybe it mandates that flushes have to be permanent when the call returns.

Comment: @EdisonvonMyosotis There is no definition of "permanent" either.

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not consider the existence of any operating system kernel or anything similar. How exactly IO works at that level is not specified. The flush only means that the internal buffer contents of the C++ stream object are written.

In any case, typical operating systems do not block until a write is actually physically completed. Instead the write is only submitted to a queue to be written by the kernel when suitable.

For performance and energy efficiency reasons the operating system typically also keeps modified file contents in memory as dirty pages to only write them back to the file system later, for example to allow disks to keep in sleep for a longer time.

A flush will not be equivalent to e.g. a `fsync` on Linux.